# Large font size of hypelink text on wordpress

Tags: css, wordpress, hyperlink, font-size, large-text

My linked text (hyperlinks) on my WordPress blog appear bigger than the other paragraph texts. I have tried a couple of CSS codes to override it but its still unchanged. Please suggest an effective CSS code that can override this issue?. See how the hyperlink appear below.

**The codes I tried**

(1)

```css
* { 
 text-decoration: none ! important; 
}
```

(2)

```css
a {
 Font-size: 12px 
}
```

How the large text size on hyperlinks appear

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your second code is almost right. You're only missing the semicolon after 15px, and the F in font-size should be lowercase.

```
a {
  font-size: 15px;
}
```

The above is correct, however if there's later class targeting to your links, or a class targeting the links inside paragraphs your styles will be overwritten. In that case you can try this.

```
a,
p a {
    font-size: 15px !important;
}
```

Make sure to add these new classes at the end/bottom of the stylesheet.

Comment: Thanks with E-Hugs.... The second code quoting the links inside paragraphs worked! I am so glad for you assistance and this community. Thanks a whole lot.